# Windows IOCTL: How to write to SD card External CSD Register?

Tags: windows, storage, sd-card, ioctl, deviceiocontrol

Can anybody guide me on how to Write into an External CSD Register of SD card on Windows through IOCTL.

I am using IOCTL_SFFDISK_DEVICE_COMMAND to send CMD6(SWITCH) and modify some fields of eMMC External CSD Register. But the DeviceIoControl throws an error (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) and I am not able to write to the register.
For example, I am trying to Write Value=0x00 to POWER_OFF_NOTIFICATION field, i.e. ExCSD[34]. Following how in linux the mmc_ioc_cmd structure is filled

`UINT32 value = (MMC_SWITCH_MODE_WRITE_BYTE << 24) | (index << 16) | (val << 8) | EXT_CSD_CMD_SET_NORMAL;`

I am filling Command Data as:

```
SFFDISK_DEVICE_COMMAND_DATA &sdcd = GetCommandData();
sdcd.HeaderSize = sizeof(SFFDISK_DEVICE_COMMAND_DATA);
sdcd.Command = SFFDISK_DC_DEVICE_COMMAND;
sdcd.ProtocolArgumentSize = sizeof(SDCMD_DESCRIPTOR);
sdcd.DeviceDataBufferSize = BufferSize;
```

And My Descriptor Data as:

```
SDCMD_DESCRIPTOR Desc;
Desc.Cmd = SDCMD_SWITCH ; /*CMD6*/
Desc.CmdClass = SDCC_STANDARD;
Desc.TransferDirection = SDTD_WRITE;
Desc.TransferType = SDTT_CMD_ONLY;
Desc.ResponseType = SDRT_1B;
```

Now, I have tired two methods of filling and sending the data:

**Method1**: Copying the data field into Information field, i.e.:

```
sdcd.Information = value;
```

**Method2**: Copying the Data field into the DataBuffer region.
My Buffer was declared as:

```
struct SDBuffer {
        char dcd[sizeof(SFFDISK_DEVICE_COMMAND_DATA)];
        SDCMD_DESCRIPTOR Descriptor;
        BYTE Buffer[0];
    } *data;
```

Thus,

```
memcpy(data->Buffer, &value, sizeof(value));
```

PS: I am already running IOCTLs to successfully read values of CID and CSD register. Also, contents of External CSD Register through IOCTL_SFFDISK_MMC_QUERY_EXT_CSD.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: With no luck from application side, I decided to write upper filter driver for SD Storage Class Controller and directly calling the SdBus Library APIs.